# Aligning label and span

Tags: html, css

I have the following form:

```
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="selectbasic">Time</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <span id="time" class="data">Some text here</span>
    <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="input-xlarge policies-form hide">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

So, as you see, the actual select form is hidden, and initially the user sees only the introductory text. My problem is that this introductory text is not perfectly lined up with the label (the bottom line of the label text is 3-4 pixels lower than the bottom line of introductory text).

I tried several CSS properties, but they don't work. How can I put them in one line?

[image]

Comment: Provide us a jsfiddle if it's possible

Comment: not sure how to activate bootstrap on jsfiddle; I added a screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this CSS: (assuming you're using `.form-horizontal` on your form tag)

```
.form-horizontal span.data {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 0; // Or however much padding you need....
}
```